# Unit testing on a python class property

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.goal = ''

    @property
    def goal(self):
        return self.goal
```

Is it possible to write a unit test on the property `goal`, given that it is not callable?

Comment: Yes. Why do assume that unittest must test callable attributes?

Comment: What would you want to test about ``goal``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
def test_goal_property(self):
    dummy_player = Player()

    self.assertEqual(dummy_player.goal, '')
```

or

```
def test_goal_property(self):
    dummy_player = Player()
    dummy_player.goal = 'something'

    self.assertEqual(dummy_player.goal, 'something')
```

Comment: Your second example fails with `AttributeError: can't set attribute`